# Group result in SQL by custom condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get images with **key_id=1** or if it absent, with **key_id=null**.

```
id | image                  | key_id 
----------------------------------
12 | default_thumbnail      | null  
12 | Abrams.png             | 1
14 | default_thumbnail      | null  
15 | default_thumbnail      | null  
15 | T34.png                | 1
15 | T34-big.png            | 3 
16 | T31.png                | 3
```

Result to be reached:

```
id | image                  | key_id 
----------------------------------
12 | Abrams.png             | 1
14 | default_thumbnail      | null  
15 | T34.png                | 1
```

I waste much time, but I can't solve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select *
from t
where key_id = 1
union all
select *
from t
where key_id is null and 
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

It is also possible to choose one row for each id using `row_number()` for prioritization:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by key_id nulls last
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
      where key_id is null or key_value = 1
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution with `array_agg()`:

```
select 
    id, 
    (array_agg(image))[1] image, 
    (array_agg(key_id))[1] key_id
from (
    select * 
    from a_table
    where key_id = 1 or key_id is null
    order by key_id nulls last
    ) s
group by 1
order by 1;

 id |       image       | key_id 
----+-------------------+--------
 12 | Abrams.png        |      1
 14 | default_thumbnail |       
 15 | T34.png           |      1
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing a group by, you need to also need to specify how to pick what to do with each field, when there are two images called default_tumbnail and you group them together, should SQL show you the key_id of the first, or the second one?

So you can select the min (or max) of each column, or group by them too to separate everything.

Example below would give you the first ID and First Key_ID for each image name.

```
Select min(ID) as FirstID, min(key_id) as FirstKeyID from YourTableName where (key_id = 1) or (key_id is null)
Group by image
```

Comment: If I need to get data by key_id > 1 , the query will return wrong result.